# Append datas to object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i have an Active Record that contains an array, which contains files ([see this](https://www.codementor.io/tips/8367241728/carrierwave-now-natively-supports-multiple-file-uploads-in-rails-gotchas)) thanks to CarrierWave and its multiupload function.

I want to extract these files and put them into a JSON. For now, the JSON part works but I have trouble adding these datas to the JSON itself.

```
  # GET /multifiles
  def index
    @fichiers = Multifile.all
    @multifile = {}
    @fichiers.each do |m|
      m.fichiers.each do |f|
        path = f.url
        @fichiers << path if path

      end
    end

    render json: @fichiers
  end
```

I read quite a lot of stackoverflow messages saying that this is the way to append some value to an object, but when I refresh, I get the following:

```
undefined method `<<' for #Multifile::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x000000122beaa0>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@fichiers` is not an array at the moment you send `<<` on it.

To make it array, replace the line

```
@fichiers = Multifile.all
```

by

```
@fichiers = Multifile.all.to_a
```

Comment: Thank you, it was silmpler that I feared!